# How to remove page title, url, datetime and page number using javascript print

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using window.print for page print. Is it possible to remove page title, URL, page number and date time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add below attribute in html tag.

**"moznomarginboxes mozdisallowselectionprint"**

```
like : <html moznomarginboxes mozdisallowselectionprint>
```

Comment: You might also want to mention that `moznomarginboxes` and `mozdisallowselectionprint` only work in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS media query:

```
@media print{

    #someElem{
        display:none;
    }

}
```

However if you're talking about external pagination, you can remove the page labels in the print page interface. Chrome supports that feature.

Comment: I think this is work with element. I need remove page URL and title.

Comment: @VishalKiri with javascript: no. You can't. However you can do it manually when printing, via the print interface